# SVM in R (package e1071): predicting class using predict()

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, e1071

I have difficulties to understand `predict.svm`. 
Please find an illustration of my confusion below.
As we can see, results are different depending on the `probability` argument of `predict()`.
So my question is: what is the difference between `probability=TRUE` and `probability=FALSE`?

```
library(e1071)

# some illustrative data
data(iris)
attach(iris)
x <- subset(iris, select=-Species)
y <- factor(Species == "setosa")

# SVM
SVM <- svm(y ~ x[, 1], probability=TRUE) 

# predictions with 'probability=FALSE'
pred <- predict(SVM, x[, 1], probability=FALSE)
table(true=iris$Species == "setosa", pred=pred)
#        pred
# true    FALSE TRUE
#   FALSE    93    7
#   TRUE      5   45

# predictions with 'probability=TRUE'
pred <- predict(SVM, x[, 1], probability=TRUE)
table(true=iris$Species == "setosa", pred=pred)
#        pred
# true    FALSE TRUE
#   FALSE    94    6
#   TRUE     10   40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation you can read that see `?svm` (or [here](http://www.inside-r.org/node/57517)):

> The probability model for classification fits a logistic distribution
>   using maximum likelihood to the decision values of all binary
>   classifiers, and computes the a-posteriori class probabilities for the
>   multi-class problem using quadratic optimization. The probabilistic
>   regression model assumes (zero-mean) laplace-distributed errors for
>   the predictions, and estimates the scale parameter using maximum
>   likelihood.

Some more information can be found in [libsvm documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/) that `svm` function uses, and in JSS article [*Support Vector Machines in R*](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v15/i09/paper).

Comment: On the one hand, when probability=FALSE, predict() uses the signs of the decision values. On the other hand, when probability=TRUE, predict() uses a fitted logistic model. Is it correct?

Comment: That is what the documentation says.